# ClassSerializer not working in NestJs with @Res decorator

Tags: nestjs, response, class-transformer

I want to exclude some fields in my response and I use ClassSerializerInterceptor but it does not work when I use @Res.

Here my entity with @Exclude

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUfgC.png)

Here my controller with @Get

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avno9.png)

And here my main where I use ClassSerializer global

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4G4v.png)

The photo below is the error that I have in VScode when I call my Api e the responde in Postman is not correct

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31pKH.png)

I have tried also @UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor) above the @Get call but I have the same issue and the field password is still present

Comment: Please edit to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.